# How to add or condition using sequelize in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, sequelize.js, react-hooks

I would like to add the below query condition in my “service/players” get userModel.findAll()...

select * from user where privilege =‘ADMIN’ or privilege = ‘PLAYER’

The below query just returns only PLAYER.

```
app.get('/service/players', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const players = await UserModel.findAll({ where: { privilege: 'PLAYER' } });
    res.status(200).json({ players });
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: e.message });
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Op.or](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html#examples-with--code-op-and--code--and--code-op-or--code-) or [Op.in](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html#shorthand-syntax-for--code-op-in--code-)

**Like this**

```js
app.get('/service/players', async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const players = await UserModel.findAll({
        where: {
          privilege: {
            [Op.or]: ['ADMIN', 'PLAYER']
          }
        }
      })
      res.status(200).json({ players });
    } catch (e) {
      res.status(500).json({ message: e.message });
    }
}
```

**or simply like this**

```js
where: {
    privilege: ['ADMIN', 'PLAYER']
  }
```

Comment: Sorry the first option is not working it giving exception in console. The `simple` option is looking good, i mean this one.. `where: {
    privilege: ['ADMIN', 'PLAYER']
  }`

Comment: great - just fyi to use Op.or you need to require it `const Op = require('Sequelize').Op` ...